# queryRenderedFeatures for heatmap-layer get nothing

Tags: mapbox, mapbox-gl-js, mapbox-gl

I use `queryRenderFeatures` to get a feature from heatmap layer,but I got nothing.

```
map.on('click',function (e) {
  const features = map.queryRenderedFeatures(e.point, {
      layers: ['my-heatmap-layer']
    });
  console.log(features)  // []
})
```

Who can give me an answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not possible with the current mapbox gl-js release(0.47.0). [source](https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-js/blob/0154e64549e9bd0ba1220a18e535fc60659b0c2a/src/style/style_layer/heatmap_style_layer.js#L60-L62)